# bigquery - Combine row data with columns of unique data

Tags: sql, transpose

can this scenario be accomplished with a single query?
read example table and transpose based on id each cat and value.
Existing Table would contain the columns and or null columns are created when
select is done (e.gl NULL Att1_Val1)

Example Table                   Existing Table
id  name   cat   value          ID Name   Att1_Val1  Att2_Val1 Att3_Val1  Att4_Val1
1   name1  att1  1              1  Name1  1          2         3          Null
1   name1  att2  2              1  Name2  4          5         6          7
1   name1  att3  3
2   name2  att1  4
2   name2  att2  5
2   name2  att3  6
2   name2  att4  7

[See snapshot for a Better view of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjwT0.png)

Comment: [minimal example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this for my real table structure (names in the example where changed and I also had a case statement. But this is the basic of how I solved.

```
Select id, Name, Att1, Att2, Att3, Att4
   FROM (SELECT id, value, att FROM 'List_table' as Source_Table)

PIVOT
 (MAX(Value) FOR att
   IN ('Att1', 'Att2', 'Att3','Att4'))
 AS Pivot_table
```